# JComponent not displaying on JPanel using GridBagLayout

Tags: java, swing, gridbaglayout, jcomponent

So after a bit of research I'm leaning toward needing to specify the preferred size of my `JComponent` before hand, since `JComponent` doses't really have a preferred size inherently.

Would adding a preferred size to my `JComponent` fix the issue with it displaying on my panel?

And if this is the way to fix the issue whats the best way to go about doing it? Ive read different people saying use `setPreferedSize` and others saying you shouldn't use this method at all.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import java.awt.Insets;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.ComponentOrientation;

public class ArrayViewer 
{
    static int[] array;
    static int[] sortedArray;

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int size=0;
        Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
        //ask for the size of the array until the user enters a size in the right range
        do
        {
            System.out.print("Enter the size of the array (should be between 10 and 100): ");
            size=in.nextInt();
        }
        while (size<10 || size>100);

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setSize(1000,1000);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        array= ArrayUtil.randomIntArray(size,200);//create a random array of given size and entries ranging from 0 to 100
        System.out.println(ArrayUtil.printArray(array));



        //Set up the content pane.
        addComponentsToPane(frame.getContentPane());

        //Display the window.
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);


    }

    public static void addComponentsToPane(Container pane) 
    {
        pane.setComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.LEFT_TO_RIGHT);
        pane.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();

        //For each component to be added to this container:

        ArrayComponent arrayGraph = new ArrayComponent(array, false);
        //...Set instance variables in the GridBagConstraints instance...
        c.ipady = 0;       //reset to default
        c.weighty = 0.0;   //request any extra vertical space
        c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.PAGE_END; //bottom of space
        c.insets = new Insets(0,0,0,0);  //no padding
        c.gridx = 0;       //begins in 1st cell of..
        c.gridwidth = 2;   //2 columns wide
        c.gridy = 1;       //2nd row
        pane.add(arrayGraph, c);


}
```

ArrayComponent class

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.JComponent;

public class ArrayComponent extends JComponent
{
    // instance variables - replace the example below with your own
    int[] theArray;
    int highlightIndex;
    boolean sorted;

    /**
     * Constructor for objects of class ArrayComponent
     */
    public ArrayComponent(int[] input, boolean sorted)
    {
        // initialise instance variables
        theArray = input;
        this.sorted = sorted;
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        if (sorted == false)
        {
            Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;
            int x = 25;
            int size = theArray.length;
            for(int i = 0; i<size; i++)
            {

                g2.drawRect(x,15,5,theArray[i]);
                x = x+10;    
            }

        }

    }
}
```

ArrayUtil class

```
public class ArrayUtil
{
    private static Random generator = new Random();

    /**
    Creates an array filled with random values.
    @param length the length of the array
    @param n the number of possible random values
    @return an array filled with length numbers between
    0 and n - 1
     */
    public static int[] randomIntArray(int length, int n)
    {  
        int[] a = new int[length];      
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
            a[i] = generator.nextInt(n);

        return a;
    }

    public static String printArray(int[] array)
    {
        String str=("array=[");
        int k=0;
        for (k=0;k<array.length-1;k++)
            str=str+array[k]+", ";              
        str=str+array[k]+"]";
        return str;
    }
```

Comment: Post an [MCVE (link)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Possibly, but there are any number of reasons that a component may not be "visible" on a container. Also, take a look at [Should I avoid the use of set(Preferred|Maximum|Minimum)Size methods in Java Swing?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7229226/should-i-avoid-the-use-of-setpreferredmaximumminimumsize-methods-in-java-swi)

Comment: I was looking over that earlier, a good bit of whats being said is above me, but ill try again. I also excluded code because my other components are working fine, i just looked up why a JComponent wouldnt show up, and preferred size issues was what I found

Comment: [Don't use `setPreferredSize()` when you really mean to override `getPreferredSize()`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7229226/230513).

Comment: Ah, ha! Thank you for the comments i overrid the getPreferredSize method and just returned the dimensions i want (ill go back later and provide max possible dimension of my component). To clarify my understanding a bit. When adding a component to the layout, the getPreferredSize method is called on each component inherently so that the layout manager will know what dimensions to use when adding it to the panel. In the case of JComponents, since they dont have a natural preferred size, overriding the method call and adding in your own fixes the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Override `getPreferredSize` rather than using `setPreferredSize`

You can also affect the size using `GridBagLayout` by specifying the `fill` property and changing the `weightx`/`y` property

Comment: why Override getPreferredSize rather than using setPreferredSize?

Comment: It is generally recommend that you override `getPreferredSize`, as it maintains the single responsibility principle, it's the component's responsibility to calculate this, not someone elses. You can also have a look at [Should I avoid the use of set(Preferred|Maximum|Minimum)Size methods in Java Swing?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7229226/should-i-avoid-the-use-of-setpreferredmaximumminimumsize-methods-in-java-swi) for more discussions on the subject.